# Does Scikit-learn support transfer learning?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn

Does `Scikit-learn` support transfer learning? Please check the following code.

model `clf`  is gotten by `fit(X,y)`

Can model `clf2` learn on the base of `clf` and transfer learn by `fit(X2,y2)` ?

---

```
>>> from sklearn import svm
>>> from sklearn import datasets
>>> clf = svm.SVC()
>>> X, y= ....
>>> clf.fit(X, y)
SVC()

>>> import pickle
>>> s = pickle.dumps(clf)
>>> clf2 = pickle.loads(s)
>>> clf2.fit(X2,y2)

>>> clf2.predict(X[0:1])
```

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but transfer learning is mostly a property of the underlying machine learning algoritm/architecture. I only know of it in the context of deep learning. I am not sure whether it makes sense to talk about "transfer learning" with support vector machines.

Comment: @cel : In my opinion transfer learning is about saving the `weights` and `architecture` of a model, and then tweaking those weights to get a lower cost on a different dataset. And since **SVM** will learn weights, according to the features and has a structure of SVM defined by the kernel, "it should be a valid scenario"

Comment: While maybe not what most would refer to as transfer learning, sklearn implements a naive Regressor chain class https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.multioutput.RegressorChain.html which uses predictions from models earlier in the chain

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the context of `scikit-learn` there's no transfer learning as such, there is incremental learning or continuous learning or online learning.

By looking at your code, whatever you're intending to do won't work the way you're thinking here. From [this](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/basic/tutorial.html#refitting-and-updating-parameters) `scikit-learn` documentation:

> Calling `fit()` more than once will overwrite what was learned by any
> previous `fit()`

Which means using `fit()` more than once on the same model will simply overwrite all the previously fitted coefficients, weights, intercept (bias), etc.

**However if you want to fit a portion of your data set and then improve your model by fitting a new data, what you can do is look for [estimators](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/computing.html#incremental-learning) that include `partial_fit` API implementation.**

> If we call `partial_fit()` multiple times, framework will update the
> existing weights instead of re-initialising them.

**Another way to do incremental learning with `scikit-learn` is to look for algorithms that support the `warm_start` parameter.**

From [this](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html) doc:

> **warm_start: bool, default=False**
>
> When set to `True`, reuse the solution of
> the previous call to `fit()` as initialization, otherwise, just erase the
> previous solution. Useless for `liblinear` solver.

Another example is [Random forrest regressor](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestRegressor.html).

Comment: Thanks for your reply！！